# jQuery Isotope masonry layout animation failing :(

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-masonry, jquery-isotope

I am trying to get [jQuery Isotope's](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/introduction.html) masonry layout to work on this test site: http://make.truliablog.com/test-filters

It appears to be sorting them properly, but the animation when you resize the window and the blocks adjust are not working. How can I fix this problem?

Here is the associated jQuery code.

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('#container').isotope({
            masonry : {
                columnWidth : 50
            }
        });

        // Filter buttons
        jQuery('#filters a').click(function(){
            var selector = jQuery(this).attr('data-filter');
            jQuery('#container').isotope({ filter: selector });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 9):

It seems Isotope has the default 'animationEngine' as 'css'.
The shortest way would be to set 'animationEngine' as 'jquery' (assuming you are using jQuery).

```
jQuery('#filters a').click(function(){
    var selector = jQuery(this).attr('data-filter');
    jQuery('#container').isotope({
        filter: selector,
        animationEngine : "jquery"
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Fixed my problem instantly in Google Chrome on Mac.